# Detecting change in pogo pin voltage android

Tags: android

I am trying to build a custom dock for the galaxy nexus using the pogo pins connection, and I am trying to find a way to detect small voltage changes across the pins. I thought about using ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED, but I'm not sure if this will give me the values that I want.

I want to know if it's possible to detect if a small voltage is being passed through the pogo pins E.g. much lower than normal charging voltage. Is this possible? Are there any guides on programming specifically for the pogo pin connectors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no such API for this.  All you can do is use ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED and save the charging rate and make a timer for check it, if it's too much time for charging 1% or even not charging up, you can say it's much lower than normal.